# SET SESSION DATEFORM = ANSIDATE doesn't seem to be working in BTEQ

Tags: teradata, bteq

This is the BTEQ call I'm using:

```
.EXPORT REPORT FILE = OUTPUT_FILE;

SET SESSION DATEFORM = ANSIDATE;

SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
;
```

Dates keep coming up as IntegerDates YY/MM/DD

Teradata 16.xx. Is this not supported by BTEQ/Unix?

---

Update:
Fred's solution (worked like a charm)

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD COLUMN_NAME DATE FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY';
```

Comment: The `SESSION DATEFORM` is a default. It applies to string values being supplied for dates or to date expressions that don't have an explicit FORMAT. It will also be used to set the FORMAT for date columns if you don't specify one in your DDL. But if a table already exists, the defined column FORMAT will override.

Comment: @Fred, could you move your comment to the answers, so I accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SESSION DATEFORM` is a default. It applies to string values being supplied for dates or to date expressions that don't have an explicit `FORMAT`. It will also be used to set the `FORMAT` for date columns if you don't specify one in your DDL. But if a table already exists, the defined column `FORMAT` will override